# Override methods with "?" parameters in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to extend the following java class in Scala

https://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serializer.html#configure(java.util.Map, boolean)

So far the code I have written is

```
package com.abhi

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer

import scala.runtime.ObjectRef

class PersonSerializer extends Serializer[Person] {
  override def configure(configs: Map[String, ObjectRef], isKey: Boolean) : Unit = {

  }

  override def serialize(topic: String, p : Person) : Array[Byte] = {
    Array[Byte]()
  }
}
```

But this gives me compile time error `method configure overrides nothing`

I have tried searching but I am not able to figure out how to override the the configure method because of the "?" in the java definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in the Serializer interface you have a java.util.Map, not scala.collection.Map. 
Also you need need to define close.
Thus you should fix your code so that is like this:

```
class PersonSerializer extends Serializer[Person] {
  override def configure(configs: java.util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean) : Unit = {

  }

  override def serialize(topic: String, p : Person) : Array[Byte] = {
    Array[Byte]()
  }

  def close() {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Notice that it's not possible possible to define a more precise type to configs Map right parameter because it is ? in its java definition, thus we should accept java.util.Map whose values can be anything(_ type in scala).